# Changing the format of data inputs for dates. From sybase to mysql

Tags: mysql, format, sybase

Changing the format of data inputs for dates. From sybase to MySQL

I am trying to see if there is a way to change the data format of dates from

```
Sybase(YYYYMMDD) to MySQL(YYYY-MM-DD)
```

I exported a Schema Script from Sybase to be use/migrate to MySQL but for one of my tables the data for the dates were enter as YYYYMMDD and is not recognize by MySQL so it just zeroes it out when attempting to insert the data.

updated format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function STR_TO_DATE to format from sybase format to MySQL format
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data from sybase in a varchar column in mysql and then convert in data by  str_to_date

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20160701','%Y%m,%d') from your_table;
```